# javascript menu items database driven

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, menu, submenu

I'm using a javascript menu from [dynamicdrive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddlevelsmenu/index.htm)

I'd tried to get the menu items from a database.
my aspx file contain the menu and it works fine when it's a static menu.
my table or my query actually produces:

```
IdPage int, PageTitle varchar(20), PageFileUrl varchar(30), ParentIdPage int
```

My methods to get data

```
    DataRow[] dataRowParent = _dataTable.Select("[ParentIdPage]=" + 0);
     foreach (DataRow dr in dataRowParent)
     {
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        //  add <a> 
        HtmlGenericControl hlink = new HtmlGenericControl("a");

        if (dr["PageFileUrl"].ToString() == "") // this item has a submenu.
        {
            li.Attributes.Add("rel", "ddsubmenu" + dr["IdPage"].ToString());

            hlink.Attributes.Add("href", "#");// link should be # when no direct link
            hlink.InnerText = dr["PageTitle"].ToString();
            li.Controls.Add(hlink);

            ulTopMenu.Controls.Add(li);

            AddNewUl((int)dr["IdPage"]);
            AddSubmenuItems(_dataTable, (int)dr["IdPage"]);
         }
        else // Direct link ,no submenu
        {
            hlink.Attributes.Add("href", dr["PageFileUrl"].ToString());
            hlink.InnerText = dr["PageTitle"].ToString();
            li.Controls.Add(hlink);

            ulTopMenu.Controls.Add(li);
        }
    }
}
 private void AddSubmenuItems(DataTable dataTable, int menuId)
{
    // create related sub menu  
    DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.RowFilter = "ParentIdPage=" + menuId;

    foreach (DataRowView subMenuItem in dataView)
    {
          // find related <ul>
        HtmlControl ulControl = (HtmlControl)FindControl("ddsubmenu" + menuId);
        //  Add new <li><a href="PageFileUrl.aspx" >page title</a> </li>
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");

        HtmlGenericControl hlink = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        hlink.Attributes.Add("href", subMenuItem["PageFileUrl"].ToString());
        hlink.InnerText = subMenuItem["PageTitle"].ToString();

        li.Controls.Add(hlink);
        li.InnerText = subMenuItem["PageTitle"].ToString();
        li.Attributes.Add("href", subMenuItem["PageFileUrl"].ToString());

        ulControl.Controls.Add(li);
    }
}

 private void AddNewUl(int menuId)
  {
    // Add new <ul id="ddsubmenu00" class= "ddsubmenustyle">
    HtmlGenericControl newUl = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
    // Set the attributes of the new ul.
    newUl.ID = "ddsubmenu" + menuId;
    newUl.Attributes.Add("class", "ddsubmenustyle");
     placeHolder1.Controls.Add(newUl);
  }
```

My problem is that submenu doesn't appear!, what is wrong? 
any help appreciated.

Comment: What HTML output is it generating...? Run the project and in the browser check what HTML output is it generating..

Comment: html output shows the desired result. but the parent menu item shown without sub items.

Comment: I can't make it out... [This is a nice tutorial that might help you to create dynamic menu](http://cybarlab.blogspot.in/2013/04/generate-dynamic-menu-in-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all, finally I figured it out:
Replace this line

```
         li.Attributes.Add("rel",""+ "ddsubmenu" + dr["IdPage"].ToString()+"");
```

with this one:

```
        hlink.Attributes.Add("rel",""+ "ddsubmenu" + dr["IdPage"].ToString()+"");
```

Now it works properly :-)